# How to convert string type to Binary type in insert query in Java servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

Here i am inserting data into sql server table in one column data type is binary type data it stores i am taking

When i trying to pass data it shows error message and how to insert this

```
String ins="insert into Users(ID,Name,Password)     values(?,?,?)";

ps.setString(1,id); 
ps.setString(2,Name); 
ps.setString(3,password);
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Olar Anddrei, I Edited my question with error

Comment: See @javaguy answer then.

Comment: @Jhon why are you removing the code/errors from question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert your password `String` object to `byte[]` and use  `preparedStatement.setBytes` method as shown below:

```
byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes();
ps.setBytes(9,passwordBytes);
```

> I am getting this error now::
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed
>   when converting the nvarchar value 'SuperUser' to **data type int**

The problem with your code is that **you are using `preparedStatement.setString` for all datatypes.**
You need to use `preparedStatement.setInt` or **other suitable methods** (look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for API) **according to the database table's column design.**

Also, **I strongly recommend to close the `preparestatement` object in the `finally` block or use try with resources**, otherwise you will run out of resources.